# I trained the stanford NER programmatically, but got no model file

Tags: stanford-nlp

```
String prop = "austen.prop";
Properties props = StringUtils.propFileToProperties(prop);
String to = props.getProperty("serializeTo");
props.setProperty("serializeTo", "C:\\ner-jxy-model.ser.gz");
SeqClassifierFlags flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(props);
CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFClassifier<CoreLabel>(flags);
crf.train();
```

and this is my austen.prop

```
#location of the training file
trainFile = train.tsv
#location where you would like to save (serialize to) your
#classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
#making it faster and smaller
serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz

#structure of your training file; this tells the classifier
#that the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in
#column 1
map = word=0,answer=1

#these are the features we'd like to train with
#some are discussed below, the rest can be
#understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
#no ngrams will be included that do not contain either the
#beginning or end of the word
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
#the next 4 deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

I trained the stanford NER programmatically, but got no model file ner-model.ser.gz.

But it works when I directly use the crf to classify.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Did you found out what was wrong ? I can't find any clue in the doc.

Comment: In your prop file I can see you wanted to serialize to some file then programatically you gave it other name... why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You need this line of code after crf.train()

```
crf.serializeClassifier("path/to/model.ser.gz");
```